# Use multiple languages on Schema.DescribeFieldResult

Tags: describefieldresult

Is it possible to pass language on Schema.DescribeFieldResult so that I can get the field labels translated in multiple languages in apex?

Answer (score 2):

No, it will return the label in the current user's language.